# creating an iterative program to estimate the root of a polynomial

Tags: c, numerical-methods, polynomial-math

Am creating a program in c which is suppose to estimate the root of a 10 order polynomial using newton raphson method. The user enters 10 coefficients and it is suppose to estimate the root of the equation. the absolute relative error is 0.00000001 and maximum number of iterations allowed are 70. sample code is below.

```
   n=0;
    while(abserr<=0.00000001){
    yold=y;
    y = y-(poly(y,coefficients,11)/poly_der(y,coefficients,11));
    ynew = y;
    error=ynew-yold;
    abserr=sqrt(error*error);

    printf("iteration x%d = %.2f error =%.2f\n",n+1,y,abserr);
    n++;
    iteration++;

    if(iteration==70){
    printf("you have reached the maximum number of iterations\n");
    break;}
    }
```

the functions poly and poly_der calculate the value of the polynomial and its derivative respectively. there defnitions are below.

```
float poly(float x, float coefficients[], int order)
    {
     int idx;
     float total;

     for (idx = 0; idx < order; idx++)
        total += coefficients[idx] * pow(x, idx);
        return total;
     }

   float poly_der(float x, float coefficients[], int order)
{
    int idx;
    float total;

    for (idx = 0; idx < order; idx++)
        total += coefficients[idx] * deri(x, idx);
    return total;
}
```

deri is function which calculates the derivative of a term in the polynomial.
Unfortunately this program produces unexpected results. i cant figure out where am wrong because it compiles and runs fine. Is there another way i can estimate the root using newton's method. How can i improve the program so it produces the required results.

Comment: Newton's method is only going to find you a single root. Why write this from scratch without consulting numerical methods tomes. For example Numerical Recipes has a code for this. I'm sure GSL does too. Is this homework?

Comment: You are only putting in 10 coefficients, but right now it is using 11 (coefficients 0-10). I would start with a lower order polynomial and solve that first before trying this. Also, is your `deri` right? It should be just `pow(x,idx-1)*idx`. While you're at it, you should only be going over the loop that involves `deri` starting from 1, not 0. If your `deri` function doesn't handle `idx=0` correctly, then that could really be throwing things off.

Comment: @David Which chapter is it exactly.please guide me.

Comment: @ Justin My deri is like this float deri(float x,int n)
   {   
         float term_der = n*pow(x,n-1);
           return term_der;
           }

Comment: even when i begin from  1 the error is still the same. and my coefficients are 11 now because am beginning at 0 to 10

Comment: @Wasswa Do you have numerical recipes? I use Laguerre's method, to be found in section 9.5 of Numerical Recipes in C, 2nd ed.

Answer (score 5):

You have several unitialized variables: `total` (twice) and seemingly `iteration` as well. If you don't initialize a variable, its value is undefined and may even differ between runs of the same program.

Do `total = 0.` before entering the loop in `poly` and `poly_der`.

Comment: iteration is initialized and i have initialized total. Its just because i didnt include it in the program. sorry about that. but now when i initialize total to 0. something strange happens. i get one answer no matter which coefficients i enter.  i still dont know what's amiss

Comment: @Wasswa: maybe that's because the user enters 10 coefficients, but you call `poly` and `poly_der` with `order` 11?

Answer (score 3):

Here are some things that might help:

1. Post the function.
2. Post what you expect the root to be.
3. Post the result you got, along with the inputs that you provided.
4. Give some idea of what starting conditions you chose, because iterative methods like N-R can give different results depending on where you start.
5. Tell us why you're certain it's not a local minimum that N-R gave you.
6. What's that deri() function?  Is that yours?